# framework not found -fobjc-arc

Tags: ios, objective-c, clang

I installed Spark Inspector to see what it was like.

I don't know for certain but I think it caused a problem with cocoapods.

I'm in the middle of trying to remove them both.

I've fixed most things but I'm not getting a build error of...

```
framework not found -fobjc-arc
```

I'm not sure where to start with this as I can't find a framework called this and I've never seen this error before.

Can someone point me in the right direction please.

Comment: That looks like a problem with one of your build command lines.  `-fobjc-arc` isn't a framework; it's a switch.  In this case, it appears to be referring to [Automatic Reference Counting](https://www.google.com/#q=objc-arc).

Comment: Excellent. This pointed me in the right direction. Under "Other linker flags" was "-framework". Delete this and it's working again. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Robert Harvey's comment got me looking in the right place.

One of the build settings had "-framework" in it.

I deleted this and it all worked fine.