# framework not found -fobjc-arc error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks

After removing SparkInspector, a rather messy process, I now have this error when I try to build:

```
framework not found -fobjc-arc
linker command failed with exit code 1
```

I have no idea how to solve this problem. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

Above the error is a paragraph listing a bunch of stuff. It contains this:

```
-dead_strip -ObjC -framework -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -larchive.2
```

I can't find where this -fobjc-arc thing is referenced otherwise, though. Searching for it in various areas gives no results.

EDIT 2:

The answer from the other question did not solve my problem.

Comment: The command line is messed up; it should be `... -framework SomeFramework -fobj-arc ...`.  You'll have to examine your project settings.

Comment: May be you misspelled in -f-objc-arc flag?

Comment: This looks promising... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16796777/framework-not-found-fobjc-arc

Comment: @trojanfoe can you elaborate? What am i looking for? what should I have that i don't?

Comment: @IanL I did that, but still got the error.

Comment: Once try any of the condition among these two -fno-ObjC-arc or -ObjC-arc instead of -fobj-arc

Comment: Open your Project Targets and check in Compile Sources whether anything relating to SparkInspector. Also, Clean Build your project. Also for precautionary measure Go to your Projetc's.xcodeproj file. Right Click. Show Package Contents. Delete .xcworkspace file and xcuserdata

Comment: @kalyanipuvvada I don't understand what you mean. What am i meant to change and where?

Comment: Check your project.pbxproj file for references to the above framework. You can find the pbxproj file inside the xcodeproj folder. (right click and select - show package contents)

Comment: @Puneet I did all that but it still has the same error.

Comment: You have a spurious `-framework` statement in one of the *Other* flags in the build settings.

Comment: @NazMir I just checked. That file has no references to the framework.

Comment: did you drag and drop any .h and .m files to your project?

Comment: This has fixed it. I didn't have that before, it was definitely gone, but re-appeared. Perhaps when i restarted XCode. Removing it has worked.